# Load transalatons from backend and use with react-i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have a requirement to implement translations for a react js project.

In my project `src/locale/i18n.js` file

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
   
  });

export default i18n;
```

And I import this file to index.js

```
import './locales/i18n'
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      <App />

    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And in my app.js

```
import { useTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lang) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {t('description.part2')}
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>EN</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('si')}>SI</button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

also, my translation keys placed in `public/locales/en/transalation.json` and `public/locales/si/transalation.json`

This setup works perfectly fine. But I need to load my translations from a backend API.
It has a few JSON files and this is the URL format

`BASEURL/locales/Language/NameSpace.json`

It has few NameSpaces such as

Reports

Common

Dashboard

So If run English translation for common NameSpace,

`BASEURL/locales/Language/NameSpace.json`
The server returns a JSON object like this

```
{
"com:search":"search",
"com:logout":"logout"
}
```

How do I call these API endpoints one time and feed this to the i18n instance? So then I can use these translation keys anywhere in the project like this

```
   <h2>{t("common:com-description")}</h2>
```

Comment: I guess it is better, if you write script for downloading translation into folder `public/locales/si/transalation.json`


(()=>
 if (!fs.existsSync(`./public/locales`)) fs.mkdirSync(`./public/locales`);

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is better, if you write script for downloading translation into folder `public/locales/si/transalation.json`

`update-i18n.js`

```
const UpdateTranslation = async()=> {
 // get translation from backend
 const data = await fetch('url') 
 
 if (!fs.existsSync(`./public/locales`)) fs.mkdirSync(`./public/locales`);
  
 [data].forEach((lang) => {
  if (!fs.existsSync(`./public/locales/${lang}`)) 
    fs.mkdirSync(`./public/locales/${lang}`);
      fs.writeFile(
        `./public/locales/${lang}/common.json`,
        JSON.stringify(result[lang], null, 2),
        function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log('Error: ', err);
          console.log(`/public/locales/${lang}/common.json - updated`);
        }
      );
   }
})
```